# tcp server client communication read() write() problems. c language

Tags: c, tcp, tcpclient

I have problem, i write a tcp client in c but problem is that client send command to server server send response to that command, response is xxx#.But in client when i read from socket i read 2 response from server for example xxx#xxx#.know client send response only for first response form server and one response is delete.this is not the same all the time for example client may read only 1 response ind will response to that.HOW TO SEARCH FOR # in char array and to extract commands and client response to all response from server.Any ideas?

i have idea for one write from client to server  to read response in client is that good idea or i write to server and in one read i read all response?

example:

client write() --------> server

client read()<---------- server response

or

client write() ---------> server

client write() ---------> server

client read() <--------- server response

Comment: It would be helpful if you share your code or atleast the snippets that shows the server/client code.

Comment: TCP does not behave as you have described. You have a bug in your invisible code. Post it for comment.

Answer (score 0):

The `receive` function in server should be active always. Hence, should be placed in a `while(1)` loop.

As and when client sends a message it should receive acknowledgement from server.

Server -> Always ready to receive.

Client -> Send and receive instantaneously.

Comment: Hard to see how this answers the question, whatever it is.